# Top menu show and hide on div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a script that should show the menu is shaking up and hide it when you go down.
Now, it works if the scroll is of the body but if i would do that with a div in overflow condition, how can i do this ?

my script is very simple

```
var lastScroll = 0;
      $('#ipotetic div').scroll(function(event){


          var st = $(this).scrollTop();
          $('.header').stop();

          if (st > 54) {

          $('.header').css({"box-shadow" : "0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)"});  

          if (st > lastScroll){
             //down
             $('.header').animate({top:'-54px'},200,'swing');
          }
          else {
             //up
             $('.header').animate({top:'0px'},200,'swing');
          }
          lastScroll = st;
          }
          else { $('.header').css({"top" : "0"}); $('.header').css({"box-shadow" : "none"}); }
      });
```

this is the div structure

```
<div class="wrap"><div class="overflower"><div class="sizer">#content</div></div></div>
```

and css

```
.wrap {height:100%;position:relative;float:left;overflow:hidden;}
.overflower {width:410px;overflow:auto;height: 100%;}
.sizer {width:390px;}
```

It works perfectly with `$(window).scroll(function(event){`
but, why with a div it doesn't work, any ideas ?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/87HMu/1/ ???

Comment: JSFiddle would be very helpful in this case..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w4epv/ @JoranDenHouting

Comment: @Ashish i know that if $(window).scroll(function(event){ it works... now, i would do it whit div... only with div.wrap, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with `<div>` as long as the content overflows and CSS `overflow:auto or scroll` is applied to the div. It's detailed on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and I've also tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/w4epv/1/).